# I need advice on using a python mysql database object

Tags: python, mysql

As the title states I need some help with Python and MySQL. I am currently studying Python further and I am focusing hard on using Python and MySQL for database design, development, administration and applications.

I am familiar with MySQL and somewhat familiar with Python. Currently I am working on object orientated programming and I am trying my hand at setting up a database connection inside of a database class and then using the class to Create, Update, Delete and Read data.

I have created a new Python object:

```
import pymysql as MySQL

class Database(object):
    Host = "127.0.0.1"
    Database = "****"
    user = "****"
    password = "****"

@staticmethod
def initialize():
    currentdb = MySQL.connect(Database.Host, Database.user, Database.password, Database.Database)
    cursor = currentdb.cursor()

@staticmethod
def insert(Table, DataDict):
    placeholders = ", ".join(["%s"] * len(DataDict))
    columns = ", ".join(DataDict.keys())
    sql = "INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES (%s)"%(Table, columns, placeholders)
    cursor.execute(sql, DataDict.values())
```

I want to know, how do I work with the cursor inside of a object? I don't know if my current approach is even close to how it should be handled, I am really not sure.

Can the cursor be initialized in this way, and then used further in the object as I intend on doing in the above extract?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't your defs be indented as part of the `Database` class and inherit `self`?

Comment: The two methods, initialize, and insert should be defined inside the class. Currently, they are outside your class and insert, cannot refer to the cursor object you have created in the initialize method. I'll post an answer in a while so that you can see the problem.

Comment: Note: if you see yourself using `@staticmethod` more than once (and usually even once), you might need to think about your architecture harder. A plain function, outside any classes, if perfectly fine.

Comment: I understand the problem, quite well. I was just confused about the implementation. To give you a bit of clarity, the courses I am currently taking are running this on a MongoDB system. Now I don't want MongoDB, I am working with MySQL. So instead of following the course to the letter, I have been trying the MySQL object using similar methods than that of the course. Needless to say, I know enough that this approach didn't feel right.

Mongo seems to use collections that can be initialized using this type of approach, but not MySQL, (obviously). That is why I asked.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to work with cursors is like this:

```
import contextlib

def doSomething():
   with contextlib.closing(database.cursor()) as cursor:
     cursor.execute(...)
   # At the end of the `with` statement, cursor is closed
```

Do not keep a cursor open for too long. Keeping a connection open for a long time, as you do, is fine. Also, read on transaction control.

If you're doing more than a handful of DB operations, consider using a library like [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) or [Pony ORM](https://ponyorm.com/).

Comment: Thanks, yes, I am well aware of what happens when leaving connections open, or even in pools (.NET 4 Half Open Connectors anyone? hahaha)

And, to be fair, I like your approach. I will try this route as well. This will allow the object to create, manipulate and close the connection in one pass, and that is something I like.

Most of my Python apps, for hardware and software, I got use to closing connections and interfaces off as soon as I don't need them anymore, so this is a serious consideration. I needed to know how to start the cursor, once I have that, then I can close it as well :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
import contextlib

def doSomething():
   with contextlib.closing(database.cursor()) as cursor:
     cursor.execute(...)
```

library for db SQLAlchemy or Pony ORM.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following code. I added the content in your initialize() to the standard python class **init** method and made the database be initialized with different types of parameters:

```
import pymysql as MySQL

class Database(object):

  def __init__(self, host, db, user, pw):
      self.currentdb = MySQL.connect(Database.host, user, pw, db)

  def insert(self, Table, DataDict):
      placeholders = ", ".join(["%s"] * len(DataDict))
      columns = ", ".join(DataDict.keys())
      sql = "INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES (%s)"%(Table, columns, placeholders)

      with self.currentdb.cursor() as db_cursor:
         db_cursor.execute(sql, DataDict.values())
```

Once you are here, then you can initialize a Database object as below and insert data:

```
my_db = Database(host="127.0.0.1", user="****", pw="****", db="****")
my_db.insert('table_name', data_dict)
```

Please note, I haven't changed your code, only presenting an organization based on your initial post that could work.

Comment: Thanks. Highly appreciate it.

The way you structured it is what my mind tells me should be done. That is why I was confused.

I am doing a course that uses MongoDB instead of MySQL. So instead of following their method, I changed it on the fly while doing the course. It seems that Mongo can be initialized this way, but even that felt and looked a bit off.

I don't get why the tutor doesn't want to do a normal __init__ and define functions. Yes, you want constant values. But if you want constants, then don't pass variable connection info. Ah well, this way I learn more hahaha

Comment: Glad that it was helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/)? This gives you a mapping between Python classes and MySQL (or any other RDBMS) tables. I've recently been using it on a fairly hefty real-world project and it seems to do the job fairly well and is easy enough to learn.

Comment: I have heard of it, but have not tried it. I am going to followup on this a bit more. Thanks.